# Protractor Issue : W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, button[class*='btn-info']) - the first result will be used

Tags: javascript, protractor

**STEPS** :

1. Navigate to https://qaclickacademy.github.io/protocommerce/shop
2. Click on Shop
3. Select some mobile brands and add to cart
4. Click on Checkout button
5. Extract the total values of each mobile and print

**Issue** : I am using the below locator to click on the Add button
[ element.all(by.css("button[class*='btn-info']")).click() ]

But seems like all the Add buttons have same code.
And by default the first Add button is cliked multiple times and the same mobile is being added repeatedly.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

**MY PROTRACTOR CODE** :

```
    describe('Assignment',function(){
        function Shopping(MobileBrand){
            //Use tag name locator when only tag name is present
            element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).each(function(value){

                //when single h4 and single a tag use them directly no need to give attribute='value'
    
                value.element(by.css("h4 a")).getText().then(function(name){
                    if(name==MobileBrand)
                    {
                        console.log("Mobile Name Retrieved" +name);
                        console.log("Mobile Name Provided" +MobileBrand);
                        //Click on Add button
                        element.all(by.css("button[class*='btn-info']")).click().then(function(){
                            browser.sleep(5000);
                        });
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        it('Task',function(){
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            browser.get("https://qaclickacademy.github.io/protocommerce/");
            element(by.linkText("Shop")).click();
    
            //Pass the mobile brands to be selected
            Shopping("Samsung Note 8");
            Shopping("Nokia Edge");
            Shopping("Blackberry");
    
            element(by.partialLinkText("Checkout")).click().then(function(){
                browser.sleep(5000);
            })
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring elementArrayFinder

```
element.all(by.css("button[class*='btn-info']")) // <--- .all means many elements
```

This means, you expect the page to have multiple elements. So you need to instruct protractor which one you want to use. For this purpose you can use [.get()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) method

This way if you do

```
element.all(by.css("button[class*='btn-info']")).get(0).click();
```

The script will click the first element of this locator. Similarly you can instruct to click second (`.get(1)`), third (`.get(2)`) elements etc

Another option is to declare a function that'll return an element by text

```
let buyPhoneButton = function (name) {
  return element(by.xpath("//a[text()=" + name + "]/ancestor::app-card//button"))
}
```

and then use it

```
buyPhoneButton("iphone X").click()
```

If helped, please accept the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot 
The second option i..e to declare a function that returns an elemnt by text worked here finally.
Thanks once again